# Send data from UNO to MQTT through NodeMCU 12E - problem

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu

i am trying to send data from ACS712 sensor which is connected to UNO (3 sensors). Everything works fine on UNO, but when I send only one value from UNO through NodeMCU 12E to MQTT server, it shows totally different number (UNO gives 0.25, mqtt shows 0 or 9 or something third). For connection btwn UNO and NodeMCU 12E i was using this picture (attached).

Here is code for UNO:

```
#include "ACS712.h"
char prva[5];
char druga[5];
char treca[5];
char cetvrta[5];
ACS712 sensor1(ACS712_30A, A0);
ACS712 sensor2(ACS712_30A, A1);
ACS712 sensor3(ACS712_30A, A2);
unsigned long last_time =0;
unsigned long current_time =0;
float Wh1 =0 ; 
float Wh2 =0 ;
float Wh3 =0 ;
float Wh4 =0 ;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensor1.calibrate();
  sensor2.calibrate();
  sensor3.calibrate();
}

void loop() {
  float V = 220;
  float I1 = sensor1.getCurrentAC();
  float I2 = sensor2.getCurrentAC();
  float I3 = sensor3.getCurrentAC();
// Serial.println(I);
  float P1 = V * I1;
  float P2 = V * I2;
  float P3 = V * I3;
  float U = P1 + P2 + P3;
  last_time = current_time;
  current_time = millis();    
   Wh1 = Wh1+  P1 *(( current_time -last_time) /3600000.0) ; 
   dtostrf(Wh1, 4, 2, prva);  
   Wh2 = Wh2+  P2 *(( current_time -last_time) /3600000.0) ; 
   dtostrf(Wh2, 4, 2, druga);  
   Wh3 = Wh3+  P3 *(( current_time -last_time) /3600000.0) ; 
   dtostrf(Wh3, 4, 2, treca);
   Wh4 = Wh4+  (P1 *(( current_time -last_time) /3600000.0))+ (P2 *(( current_time -last_time) /3600000.0))+  (P3 *(( current_time -last_time) /3600000.0)) ;
   dtostrf(Wh4, 4, 2, cetvrta);
  Serial.print( " (1) W: " );     
  Serial.print(prva);
  Serial.print("   ");
  Serial.print( " (2) W: " );     
  Serial.print(druga);
  Serial.print("   ");
  Serial.print( " (3) W: " );     
  Serial.print(treca);
  Serial.print("   ");
  Serial.print( " (4) W: " );
  Serial.print(cetvrta);
  Serial.print("          ");
  Serial.print(P1);
  Serial.print("  W/h (1)");
  Serial.print("      ");
  Serial.print(P2);
  Serial.print("  W/h (2)");
  Serial.print("      ");
  Serial.print(P3);
  Serial.print("  W/h (3)");
  Serial.print("          ");
  Serial.print(U);
  Serial.print("  W/h (1,2,3)");
   delay(10000);
  Serial.println();
```

Here is code for NodeMCU 12E: (here i want to send only one data named cetvrta.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "Adafruit_MQTT.h"
#include "Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h"
#define WLAN_SSID       "Qwerty"
#define WLAN_PASS       "123456"
char cetvrta[5];
#define AIO_SERVER      "io.adafruit.com"
#define AIO_SERVERPORT  1883                   
#define AIO_USERNAME    "werty"
#define AIO_KEY         "12345"

WiFiClient client;

Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish Power = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/power");
//Adafruit_MQTT_Publish bill = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/bill");
void MQTT_connect();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println(F("Adafruit MQTT demo"));

  // Connect to WiFi access point.
  Serial.println(); Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(WLAN_SSID);

  WiFi.begin(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // Ensure the connection to the MQTT server is alive (this will make the first
  // connection and automatically reconnect when disconnected).  See the MQTT_connect
  // function definition further below.
  MQTT_connect();

 int i=0;
 float watt1;
 if(Serial.available() > 0 ){
   delay(1000); //allows all serial sent to be received together
    while(Serial.available() && i<6) {
     cetvrta[i++] = Serial.read();
    }
    cetvrta[i++]='\0';
  }

 watt1 = atof(cetvrta);
  Serial.print(F("\nSending Power val "));
  Serial.println(watt1);
  Serial.print("...");

  if (! Power.publish(watt1)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed"));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("OK!"));
  }


delay(3000);
}

// Function to connect and reconnect as necessary to the MQTT server.
// Should be called in the loop function and it will take care if connecting.
void MQTT_connect() {
  int8_t ret;

  // Stop if already connected.
  if (mqtt.connected()) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("Connecting to MQTT... ");

  uint8_t retries = 3;
  while ((ret = mqtt.connect()) != 0) { // connect will return 0 for connected
       Serial.println(mqtt.connectErrorString(ret));
       Serial.println("Retrying MQTT connection in 5 seconds...");
       mqtt.disconnect();
       delay(5000);  // wait 5 seconds
       retries--;
       if (retries == 0) {
         // basically die and wait for WDT to reset me
         while (1);
       }
  }
  Serial.println("MQTT Connected!");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128296/discussion-on-question-by-zoran-perovic-send-data-from-uno-to-mqtt-through-nodem).